# fopen doesn't work when site is open by "links" command when using CRON

Tags: php, hyperlink, cron, fopen

I have a CRON request which works (calls and returns some results).

```
* * * * * links -dump https://my.domain/cron.php > /home/users/wooqash/public_html/my.domain/cron.txt 2>> /home/users/wooqash/public_html/my.domain/cron_errors.txt
```

cron.php file:

```
<?php
$filename = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."cron.txt";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $filesize = filesize($filename);
    echo $filesize."<br />";
    if ($filesize) {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        echo "1<br />";
        echo fread($file, $filesize)."<br />";
        fclose($file);
    }
    echo "2<br />";
}
echo "<br />";
echo "test ".time();
?>
```

When I open this page in my web browser (https://my.domain/cron.php) everything is work ok:

```
30
1
0 2 test 1576699141
2

test 1576699151
```

but when code was running by CRON:

```
   0
   2

   test 1576699141
```

I can't using `wget` or `curl` on this hosting and `links` doesn't works perfectly. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're facing this issue is that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is not set when running in cli mode.

Try to use __DIR__ to get the folder that your file is at, like this:

```php
<?php

$filename = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cron.txt';
```

Comment: This isn't change anything... Still works in the same way.

Comment: Try printing out the filename in your log file

Comment: In both ways `echo __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;` return `/home/users/wooqash/public_html/my.domain/`.

Comment: Are you getting this via cli ? Or are you getting this message in the browser ?

Comment: I open a `cron.txt` file after completing the CRON task at full minute.

Comment: Ok, so which user did you use to setup this cron ? Are you sure this user can do file operations in the machine ? What is the permission of your cron.php file ?

Comment: I can't change users or something. I can only set [this](https://i.imgur.com/dDzeWPK.png) in panel.

Comment: Can you somehow access php error logs on the panel ? This filesize function should generate a E_WARNING if something goes wrong, the full error message might be there.